# 'Unable to contact the firebase server'

Tags: android, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I am working on ionic hybrid mobile app using angularFire. I am implementing email/password authentication using $firebaseAuth service. It is working properly on chrome browser but when installed on android device it is giving error 'Unable to contact the Firebase server.' My andorid application has full network access permission and permissions to use data and wify.

code and APK link
https://github.com/ajayparsana/MyFirebaseApp

Please help.

Comment: Is this still giving you problems?  Firebase services sometimes go down - not often, but occasionally it is on their end.  I've changed code thinking I was doing something wrong - if it's an intermittent thing you can always check firebase status at http://status.firebase.com/

Comment: It is always giving problem. I don't know why it is working on browser but not on mobile device. If I host website and access via mobile browser everything works fine but as soon as I build apk file & try to login I am getting error. Is there specific configuration that needs to be done?

Comment: any help will be appreciated. Its blocker to me please help.

Comment: I am also facing exactly same problem. Did you find solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed cordova inappbrowser & whitelist plugin and also add below lines in config.xml file after  line to solve my problem

```
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*.firebaseio.com" />
    <allow-intent href="auth.firebase.com" />
```